# Mocking Overloaded method with Gmock

Tags: c++, unit-testing, overloading, googletest, googlemock

I have an interface like this:

```
class AInterface {
public:
    /// The different states the =A can be in
    enum class State {
        IDLE,
        BUSY
    };

    
    struct AMetadata {
    /**
     * Default constructor
     */
    AMetadata() = default;

    AMetadata(State state)
    : state(state){}


    State state = State::IDLE;
    };

    /// Destructor.
    virtual ~AInterface() = default;

    virtual void onStateChanged(State state){}; // deprecated but still have to be here
    virtual void onStateChanged(const AMetadata& metadata){}; // i am adding this method
};
```

my mock class is defined like this

```
class MockObserver : public AInterface {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD1(onStateChanged, void(State state));
    MOCK_METHOD1(onStateChanged, void(const AMetadata& metadata));
};


// arg is passed to the matcher implicitly
// arg is the actual argument that the function was called with
MATCHER_P(AMetadataMatcher, expectedMetadata, "") {
    return arg.state == expectedMetadata.state;
}
```

Basically in the test code the implementation looks like this where the previous arg was State but now the arg have to be AMetadata

```
EXPECT_CALL(*m_mockObserver, onStateChanged(_)).Times(AnyNumber());

EXPECT_CALL(*m_mockObserver, onStateChanged(AInterface::State::BUSY))
            .WillOnce(Invoke([&](AMetadata metadata) {
                EXPECT_EQ(...,...);
            }));
EXPECT_CALL(*m_mockObserver, onStateChanged(AInterface::State::IDLE))
            .WillOnce(Invoke([&](AMetadata metadata) {
                EXPECT_EQ(...,...);
            }));
```

Compiling as is obviously i get compilation error

```
ATest.cpp:: error: call to member function 'gmock_onStateChanged' is ambiguous
    EXPECT_CALL(*m_mockObserver, onStateChanged(_).Times(AnyNumber()));
```

I tried ::testing::TypedEq and ::testing::An like below, i still get compilation error

```
EXPECT_CALL(*m_mockObserver, onStateChanged(::testing::TypedEq<const AMetadata&>(_))).Times(AnyNumber());
```

ATest.cpp:1288:49: error: no matching function for call to 'TypedEq'
EXPECT_CALL(*m_mockObserver, onStateChanged(::testing::TypedEq<const AMetadata&>())).Times(AnyNumber());

i even tried custom matcher something like

```
AMetadata metadata;
metadata.state = IDLE;
EXPECT_CALL(*m_mockObserver, onStateChanged(AMatcher<const AMetadata&>(metadata)).Times(AnyNumber()));
```

I am still getting error, so I am not sure what the best way to work with overloaded functions in gmock, basically I need to write calls where expect calls needs to work on values within a struct and I am in a situation where not only the overloaded method have the same name but same number of arguments as well, any guidance or code snippet would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to help you, but you made all possible for making help impossible. It's too much syntax errors due to the garbage ... and other undeclared names, too far to reaching the ambiguity error.

Comment: Please explain with some more sentences in general what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this presented solution in [google test documentation](https://google.github.io/googletest/gmock_cook_book.html#SelectOverload)

**Selecting Between Overloaded Functions**

If you expect an overloaded function to be called, the compiler may need some help on which overloaded version it is.

To disambiguate functions overloaded on the const-ness of this object, use the Const() argument wrapper.
using ::testing::ReturnRef;

```
class MockFoo : public Foo {
  ...
  MOCK_METHOD(Bar&, GetBar, (), (override));
  MOCK_METHOD(const Bar&, GetBar, (), (const, override));
};

...
  MockFoo foo;
  Bar bar1, bar2;
  EXPECT_CALL(foo, GetBar())         // The non-const GetBar().
      .WillOnce(ReturnRef(bar1));
  EXPECT_CALL(Const(foo), GetBar())  // The const GetBar().
      .WillOnce(ReturnRef(bar2));
```

(Const() is defined by gMock and returns a const reference to its argument.)

To disambiguate overloaded functions with the same number of arguments but different argument types, you may need to specify the exact type of a matcher, either by wrapping your matcher in Matcher(), or using a matcher whose type is fixed (TypedEq, An(), etc):

```
using ::testing::An;
using ::testing::Matcher;
using ::testing::TypedEq;

class MockPrinter : public Printer {
 public:
  MOCK_METHOD(void, Print, (int n), (override));
  MOCK_METHOD(void, Print, (char c), (override));
};

TEST(PrinterTest, Print) {
  MockPrinter printer;

  EXPECT_CALL(printer, Print(An<int>()));            // void Print(int);
  EXPECT_CALL(printer, Print(Matcher<int>(Lt(5))));  // void Print(int);
  EXPECT_CALL(printer, Print(TypedEq<char>('a')));   // void Print(char);

  printer.Print(3);
  printer.Print(6);
  printer.Print('a');
}
```

I hope this will help